# Jenkins Downloading Credentials Plugin Fails

Tags: jenkins

When trying to install the Credentials plugin I get the below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Downloaded file /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/credentials.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-256, expected 'aOL2h5pdLc9JurZ3f2StxSx6IB4dVCcMkNWPj7jwb2A=', actual 'jJUDrnXQLxirWW9U/HGMuNjFMt3HeN1xuAlb2crB6ts='
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.throwVerificationFailure(UpdateCenter.java:2033)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.verifyChecksums(UpdateCenter.java:2068)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob.replace(UpdateCenter.java:2258)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.install(UpdateCenter.java:1344)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1879)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2171)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1850)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:121)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Has anyone encountered this before and able to solve it?